# AppEngine java application ignores app.yaml

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I downloaded the sample Java project:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-try-java

I am able to deploy it in the AppEngine standard environment, but I am not able to pass my custom `app.yaml` configuration file in which I define some environment variables. For that I created `app.yaml` in `/src/main/appengine/`.

Is there way to configure this directly in the `pom.xml` file?

I tried to run:

```
mvn clean appengine:deploy -Dapp.deploy.appEngineDirectory=src/main/appengine/
```

However that doesn't make any difference and I when I see:

```
[INFO] GCLOUD: Services to deploy:
[INFO] GCLOUD:
[INFO] GCLOUD: descriptor:      [/target/appengine-staging/app.yaml]
```

When I open this `app.yaml`, my config file is not included and ignored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Java standard environment by default uses the `appengine-web.xml` file, not the `app.yaml` file. And yes, it's possible to set environment variables in it. From the [appengine-web.xml Reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref):

> Optional. The appengine-web.xml file can define environment variables
>   that are set when the application is running.
>
> ```
> <env-variables>
>   <env-var name="DEFAULT_ENCODING" value="UTF-8" />
> </env-variables>
> ```

The app you downloaded has the file in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml